# connect prestodb through sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, presto

I'd like to connect to prestodb with SQLalchemy interface. I'm running `prestodb==0.7.0` and `SQLalchemy== 1.4.20` and SQLalchemy doesn't seem to have prestodb baked in:

```
NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:presto
```

Not much luck with registering the `prestodb` either:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry
import prestodb
from prestodb.dbapi import  Connection

registry.register('presto', 'prestodb.dbapi', 'Connection')

from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine 
port = 8889
user = os.environ["USER"]
engine = create_engine(f'presto://{user}@presto:{port}/hive',
                       connect_args={'protocol': 'https', 'requests_kwargs': {'verify': False}}) 
db = engine.raw_connection()

# AttributeError: type object 'Connection' has no attribute 'get_dialect_cls'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [Dialects docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/) you will see that `Presto` is a external dialect and needs to be installed separately. The Presto dialect is supported through [PiHyve](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive#sqlalchemy) and can be installed using `pip install 'pyhive[presto]'`.